# How Can I Use Different Versions of the Same Package at the Same Time?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, twitter, instagram-api

## Problem

I'm trying to use [dart_twitter_api](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_twitter_api), [youtube_api](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api) and [instagram_media](https://pub.dev/packages/instagram_media) in my project.

Each of these require [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package but version are different.

So when I try to install `instagram_media`, an error occurs.

> Because dart_twitter_api >=0.4.0 depends on http ^0.13.0 and every version of instagram_media depends on http ^0.12.0, dart_twitter_api >=0.4.0 is incompatible with instagram_media.

> So, because MyProject depends on both dart_twitter_api ^0.5.6+1 and instagram_media any, version solving failed.
> pub finished with exit code 65

## Pubspec.yaml

My `pubspec.yaml` is below.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  dart_twitter_api: ^0.5.6+1
  youtube_api: ^1.0.4

  http: any

  # ..... other pubs
```

## Required http versions

| Package | Required http version |
| --- | --- |
| dart_twitter_api >=0.4.0 | ^0.13.0 |
| youtube_api 1.0.4 | ^0.13.3 |
| instagram_media >= any | ^0.12.0 |

Strange thing is that `dart_twitter_api` and `youtube_api` can live together,
and only when I do `flutter pub add instagram_media`, this error occurs.

## What I Want to Do

As I said earlier,I want to use [dart_twitter_api](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_twitter_api), [youtube_api](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api) and [instagram_media](https://pub.dev/packages/instagram_media) in one project.

How can I use `http ^0.13.3` and `http ^0.12.0` at the same time?

Like below;

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.13.3
  http: ^0.12.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By editing `pubspec.yaml` like;

```
dependency_overrides:
  http: ^0.13.4
```

I could implement `instagram_media` to my project.