# Flutter packages depends on different version of sprintf - is it possible to solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I am using these 2 packages:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  (...other dependecies here)
  device_calendar: ^4.2.0
  flutter_quill: ^6.1.6
```

I am unable to compile/run my app, because `device_calendar` needs `sprintf ^6.0.0`, while `flutter_quill` needs `sprintf ^7.0.0`.

Exact message is as follows:

```
Because flutter_quill >=6.1.6 depends on i18n_extension ^6.0.0 which depends on sprintf ^7.0.0, flutter_quill >=6.1.6 requires sprintf ^7.0.0.
And because device_calendar 4.2.0 depends on sprintf ^6.0.0 and no versions of device_calendar match >4.2.0 <5.0.0, flutter_quill >=6.1.6 is incompatible with device_calendar ^4.2.0.
So, because MY_APP_NAME  depends on both device_calendar ^4.2.0 and flutter_quill ^6.1.6, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because MY_APP_NAME depends on both device_calendar ^4.2.0 and flutter_quill ^6.1.6, version solving failed.)
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: device_calendar rules. i18n_extension 5.0.1 works with sprintf 6. So one way to fix it would be using flutter_quill 6.1.5 that requires  i18n_extension 5.0.1

Comment: So are you saying that if one package upgrade some lib to newer version, and other didn't z there's no way to make it work unless devs of 2nd package upgrades it as well?

Comment: You can try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641717/how-can-i-use-different-versions-of-the-same-package-at-the-same-time for sprintf, but I don't know if it works or throws an error or nothing happens.